# Problem with Javascript loading in an image on the computer in a Tauri webapp, error: "Tauri Not allowed to load local resource"

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

## more on the problem

I would like to load an image on the computer using an absolute path in Javascript.

```
const image = new Image()
image.onload = function() => redraw();
image.src = absolutePath;
```

When I build the --debug version and run it the console errors: "Tauri Not allowed to load local resource: absolutePath".
After that it (understandably) gives another error:  Failed to execute 'drawImage' [...] The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state "

Some more info: (potentially helpful)
I'm using Tauri + Vanilla HTML, JS, CSS + Rust.
I generated and saved the image using a Rust command invoked in the JS and am trying to put that image into a canvas on the HTML using JS. The Rust part saves the image to the same directory the .exe is in.
build.withGlobalTauri is set to true and am using `const invoke = window.__TAURI__.invoke` for the invoke command.

## things i tried

I have tried setting tauri.allowlist.fs.scope = ["**"] in tauri.conf.json but it did not change anything.

I expected that would allow the JS to access to "load [the] local resource"

## my desperation

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while and have found little help from the docs or other sources.

Comment: Not familiar with Tauri, but I did a direct search for your error message "Tauri Not allowed to load local resource", and got this https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/1438

Comment: Thank you for showing this, I'll check it out!